# Can I deduct a repair/replacement cost from my rent if the landlord endlessly stalls on fixing it?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, landlord, pennsylvania

I have been living in a townhome in Philadelphia, PA for a little over 2 months. There have been endless repairs needed on the home (all due to previous tenants/times) which the landlord has gotten to slowly, but one particular defect has taken such a long time that it has basically been broken the whole time. I have read that the **Implied Warranty of Habitability** allows me (and my roommates) to pay to fix the problem ourselves, and then deduct this cost from the rent if the landlord doesn't make the repairs. I have a few questions regarding this:

- At what point can it be considered that the landlord is 'not making repairs'? It has been nearly 2 months, but she technically doesn't refuse to make the repairs. She just communicates very slowly about it and provides differing explanations as to why it hasn't yet been fixed.
- Do we have full discretion to pick the repair (within reason, of course)? What if we believe the item needs replaced instead?
- I would classify that the priority of this 2-month-needed repair/replacement is about an 8.5. We have another repair need that has been unfulfilled for ~2 weeks with a priority of 11/10 (our fridge does not maintain low enough temp). Can I decide to utilize the Implied Warranty of Habitability for this because of its importance despite the short timing?
- **BIG CAVEAT**: Our lease only has 3 people on it, though there are 4 people living in the house. We have written record that our landlord is completely and fully aware of this. I believe the reason for this is that the landlord was not allowed to lease it out to 4 people (because of some Philly, PA statute related to the house type/rooms I would imagine), but chose to do so anyway. Would this impact our ability to fight in court if necessary? They specifically directed us to only put 3 on the lease despite knowing we are 4.

**Relevant clauses in lease regarding landlord repair responsibility**: "Landlord agrees to keep in good repair and working order the electrical, plumbing, sanitary, heating, air conditioning, and all other services"

Comment: It depends on what the problem is. If it's a leaky faucet then probably not. If it's a non functioning HVAC, then probably yes. What is broken? The other alternative would be that you may be able to break your lease without penalty.

Comment: @RonBeyer the two major issues are a broken stove hood (meaning we cannot fan off smoke while cooking, so the alarms go off) and that the fridge doesn't maintain the appropriate temperature, so our food spoils.